# Turn off \ turn on the sim card programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, sim-card

I am interested in a simple widget (so it seems).

The essence of the widget is as follows: after installation, you can add buttons to the screen on / off the SIM card 1 and on / off sim card 2. That's all.

It is very similar to the standard widgets for intrenetu, GPS, etc.

How to access the SIM card program?

Comment: http://kasperholtze.com/android/how-to-make-a-simple-android-widget/

Comment: Are you building your own ROM? If not, you can not access multiple SIM cards.

Comment: @ozbek i'm building my own ROM please guide how to do it?